# Multiple regexp_replace in one sql query

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have column of data:

```
WORD WORD WORD "WORD"
WORD WORD WORD "WORD W WORD WORD - WORD" BY J.J.ABRAMS W. WORD
TEXT Т TEXT TEXT "TEXT TEXT "TEXT TEXT" BY K.K.KAIE
TEXT Т TEXT TEXT "TEXT TEXT "TEXT "TEXT TEXT" BY J.J.KAIE
```

I want to select this data and get:

```
Word word word "Word"
Word word word "Word w word word - word" by J.J.Abrams w. Word
Text t text text "Text text "Text text" by K.K.Kaie
Text t text text "Text text "Text "Text text" by J.J.Kaie
```

My steps:

1) I use lower function
2) To upper first letter i can use function:

```
UPPER(LEFT(data,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(data,2,LEN(data)))
```

My problem is:
1) I can not to upper first letter after "
2) I can not to upper Name cause this construction doesnt works:

```
regexp_replace(lower(data), '.\..\..', upper('\\1'), 'g')
```

3) I dont know how it do in one query, construction like replace(replace(replace( i know but think it not good use it

The big problem that i dont know how much " can be contained in text.
I use Postgresql.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Look for proper case cases

Comment: Sorry but how it can help me for problem 1?

Comment: This question is too broad. First, try to identify exact syntax rules when a letter should be upper case.